# How to delete a file in a directory using PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete a given file from a directory using PHP. Here is the code I've tried:

```
// Get the file name
$id = '61514';

// Get the folder path
$uploads_folder_dir = 'some/dir';

// Check if the directory exists
if ( ! file_exists( $uploads_folder_dir ) )
    return false;

// Open the directory
if ( $dir = opendir( $uploads_folder_dir ) ) {

    // Loop through each file in the directory
    while ( false !== ( $file = readdir( $dir ) ) ) {

        // Target the file to be deleted and delete. All files in folder are .png
        if ( $file == ( $id . '.png' ) )
            @unlink( $uploads_folder_dir . '/' . $file );
    }
}
// Housekeeping
closedir( $dir );
@rmdir( $uploads_folder_dir );
```

Each time I run the code, the particular file I'm trying to delete is not deleted.

My guess is when I'm looping through the directory, my logic to find the file isn't working. I can confirm that file `61514.png` is definitely in directory `some/dir`

Hoping someone can spot where I'm going wrong here?

Comment: could you do a error_log instead of @unlink so you can see if the file path is correct, it might be that your script is a folder above or bellow where the image is

Comment: Have you tried putting various debug messages throughout your code to see if any sections aren't being hit? Also try removing the `@` from infront of unlink to see any errors that throws. Maybe PHP doesn't have the permissions to remove the file.

Comment: If you have the filename at the start, why are you searching the whole directory for the file?

Comment: A little sidenote about [`rmdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php). *"Attempts to remove the directory named by dirname. The directory must be empty, and the relevant permissions must permit this."* - So, make sure the folder is indeed empty when attempting to use this function.

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys! Debugging as you suggested helped me pinpoint the issue to my path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First debug your file path is ok or not just by printing whole file path like

```
// Target the file to be deleted and delete. All files in folder are .png
        if ( $file == ( $id . '.png' ) ){
             echo $uploads_folder_dir . '/' . $file; die;
             @unlink( $uploads_folder_dir . '/' . $file );
        }
    }
```

Comment: My path was indeed the problem. Debugging that helped. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you loop through the files? This one would be much easier:

```
// Get the file name
$id = '61514';
// Get the folder path
$uploads_folder_dir = 'some/dir';
// Check if the directory exists
if ( ! file_exists( $uploads_folder_dir ) )
    return false;

unlink("$uploads_folder_dir/$id.png");

// Housekeeping
@rmdir( $uploads_folder_dir );
```

Comment: I also think he must use unlink and check permissions.

Comment: Good point. I've removed my while loop as you're right, it wasn't necessary

Answer (score 0):

@unlink -> use unlink and if you don't see permission denied problem, the file and "dir" should be removed.